# Replacing part of Numpy 2D Array using list in both rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, replace

Let's import `numpy` first,

```py
import numpy as np
```

For example, I have a matrix A as,

```py
A = np.identity(10)
```

I have two other matrices as,

```py
B = np.random.sample((4, 4))
C = np.random.sample((6, 6))
```

In addition, I have two lists of indices as,

```py
idx_1 = [1, 2, 4, 7]
idx_2 = [0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Now I want to replace `idx_1` rows and columns of A by B and `idx_2` rows and columns of A by C. The final A matrix will be a block diagonal matrix.

What is the efficient way to achieve this?

I tried as follows but I did not change A, I don't know why, but I did not get any error as well.

```py
A[idx_1][:,idx_1] = B
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what "Now I want to replace idx_1 rows and columns of A by B" would look like? Like, the actual output of that step

Comment: `A[[idx_1] * 4, [idx_1] * 4] = B`

Comment: You can't use a cascaded indexing because the first creates a copy.  You have to use one indexing expression, `A[...] = B`, indexing on both rows and columns at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [99]: A = np.identity(10).astype(int)
In [100]: A
Out[100]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
In [101]: idx_1 = [1, 2, 4, 7]
```

I can select a set of diagonal values with:

```
In [102]: A[idx_1, idx_1]
Out[102]: array([1, 1, 1, 1])
In [103]: A[idx_1, idx_1] = [10,20,30,40]
In [104]: A
Out[104]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 30,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 40,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1]])
```

But it looks like you want to replace a (4,4) block of values.  We have to  construct a pair on indices that together `broadcast` to the shape, that is (4,1) array with a (1,4) array.

```
In [105]: np.ix_(idx_1, idx_1)
Out[105]: 
(array([[1],
        [2],
        [4],
        [7]]), array([[1, 2, 4, 7]]))

In [106]: A[np.ix_(idx_1, idx_1)]
Out[106]: 
array([[10,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 20,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 30,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 40]])
In [107]: A[np.ix_(idx_1, idx_1)] += 1
In [108]: A
Out[108]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1, 21,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0, 31,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0, 41,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1]])
```

The equivalent indexing with nested lists is:

```
In [109]: A[[[1],[2],[4],[7]],[[1,2,4,7]]]
Out[109]: 
array([[11,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, 21,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1, 31,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 41]])
```

---

Regarding your indexing attempt:

```
In [110]: A[idx_1]   # A[idx_1,:]
Out[110]: 
array([[ 0, 11,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1, 21,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0, 31,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0, 41,  0,  0]])
In [111]: A[idx_1][:,idx_1]
Out[111]: 
array([[11,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1, 21,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1, 31,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, 41]])
```

`In[111]` is evaluated in 2 steps; first rows are selected, and then columns.

In

```
A[idx_1][:,idx_1] = B
```

the values of `B` will replace columns in `Out[110]`.  But that's a copy of values from `A`, not a `view`.  So a good grasp of the difference between view and copy, and between basic and advanced indexing is important when working with `numpy`.